# How do you find the sample space of flipping unfair coins?

Tags: statistics, data-science

So, usually for unbiased coins, the probability of getting 2 heads out of 3 flips is - `3C2 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 = 3/8`, since we know, the formula for probability is likely events divided by all possible events; we can say that there are 8 possible events here.

Now flip an unbiased coin with the probability of getting heads 80% of the time,
so the probability of getting 2 heads out of 3 flips is -
`3C2 * 0.8 * 0.8 * 0.2 = 3/7.8125`, so is the sample space 7.8125 here ?

Answer (score 0):

It is still 8. 8 possible results. It's all about classical definition of probability.

In first example (p=50%) each possible result (for example {head, head, not_head}) has the same probability, that's why we can calculate

`**total_prob = count_success/count_total = 3*1.000/8 = 0.375**`

In the second (p=80%) we don't have this assumption anymore, so cannot use classical definition of probability (count_success/count_total), so we have to calculate

`**total_prob = sum_success/count_total = 3*1.024/8 = 0.384**`

In general, You can imagine, that in 1st example each result has weight=**1.000**, and in 2nd example results have different weights (for example {head, head, not_head} has weight=**1.024** and {not_head, not_head, not_head} has weight=**0.064**)